# AngularJs crear un menu sideBar desplegable

Tags: angularjs, angular-directivas

Hola comunidad estoy tratando de crear un menu desplegable en un sideBar para la parte administrativa. El problema que resulta es que cuando hago click en un sub-menu se despliegan todos los sub-menus y viceversa. Aquí esta mi código. Espero que puedan ayudarme.

```
<div class="side-bar hide-on-med-and-down">
    <div class="row profile-side-bar">
        <div class="col s4">
            <img class="circle responsive-img" ng-src="assets/img/avatar.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col s8">
            <p>User Name</p>
            <small>Administrador</small>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="white-text" ng-click="openBar = !openBar"><i class="material-icons">menu</i> <span ng-class="{'text-open-side-bar': !openBar, 'text-close-side-bar': openBar}">MENÚ</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="material-icons">dashboard</i><span ng-class="{'text-open-side-bar': !openBar, 'text-close-side-bar': openBar}">Texto menu</span></a></li>
        <li class="sub-nav">
            <a ng-click="childrenOpen = !childrenOpen"><i class="material-icons">dashboard</i><span ng-class="{'text-open-side-bar': !openBar, 'text-close-side-bar': openBar}">Texto menu</span><i class="nav-down material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</i></a>
            <ul class="children" ng-class="{'show-children':childrenOpen,'hide-children':!childrenOpen}">
                <li><a href="#">Item #1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item #2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item #3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item #4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="material-icons">dashboard</i><span ng-class="{'text-open-side-bar': !openBar, 'text-close-side-bar': openBar}">Texto menu</span></a></li>
        <li class="sub-nav">
            <a ng-click="childrenOpen = !childrenOpen"><i class="material-icons">dashboard</i><span ng-class="{'text-open-side-bar': !openBar, 'text-close-side-bar': openBar}">Texto menu</span><i class="nav-down material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</i></a>
            <ul class="children" ng-class="{'show-children':childrenOpen,'hide-children':!childrenOpen}">
                <li><a href="#">Item #1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item #2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item #3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item #4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Al hacer click se despliega los dos `class="sub-nav"`, esto es lógico porque cambia el $scope, pero como podría hacer que solo se despliege el submenu donde hice click. Gracias por sus amables respuestas

Comment: Como recomendación: utiliza plunkr o codepen para ver una vista previa de la funcionalidad.

Comment: Tu sidebar tiene un controller o forma parte de una directiva?

Comment: Gracias por las recomendaciones, si esta dentro de un controller pero no hay nada en este ya que no hace falta por que el ng-click solo me devuelve verdadero o falso pero se despliega los dos submenus y alguna vez mire en un video que solo se activa el sub-menu donde presiono click

Answer (score 3):

Usualmente los sidebars los puedes construir a partir de objetos ya que agregar y quitar objetos es mucho más sencillo(salvo algunas ocasiones) que manipular todo el html.

Te dejo un ejemplo donde escribí dos directivas, una para el componente sidebar y otra para cada menuitem que permite mantener la lógica de cada componente por separado. Ahora es solo cuestión de agregar y quitar elementos y customizar a tu gusto.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('sidebar', function(menuitems) {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      template: '<ul class="sidebar">' +
        '<li class="menuitem" ng-class="{active: item.active, subitems: !!item.subitems}" ng-repeat="item in menuitems" ng-click="toogleItem($index)">' +
        '<a ng-href="{{item.href}}" ng-if="item.href">{{item.title}}</a>' +
        '<menuitem item="item" ng-if="!item.href"></menuitem>' +
        '</li>' +
        '</ul>',
      link: function($scope) {
        $scope.menuitems = menuitems;

        $scope.toogleItem = function(index) {
          $scope.menuitems.forEach(function(item, idx) {
            item.active = index === idx && (!item.active || !item.subitems);

            if (!item.active && item.subitems) {
              item.subitems.forEach(function(si) {
                si.active = false;
              });
            }
          });
        }
      }
    };
  })
  .directive('menuitem', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
        item: '='
      },
      template: '<span>{{item.title}}</span>' +
        '<ul ng-if="item.subitems" ng-show="item.active">' +
        '<li class="menuitem sub" ng-repeat="subitem in item.subitems" ng-class="{active: subitem.active}" ng-click="toogleSubItem($event, $index)">' +
        '<a ng-href="{{subitem.href}}" ng-if="subitem.href">{{subitem.title}}</a>' +
        '<span ng-if="!subitem.href">{{subitem.title}}</span>' +
        '</li>' +
        '</ul>',
      link: function($scope, $element) {
        $scope.toogleSubItem = function($event, index) {
          $event.stopPropagation();
          $scope.item.subitems.forEach(function(item, idx) {
            item.active = index === idx;
          });
        }
      }
    };
  })
  .factory('menuitems', function() {
    return [{
      title: 'Item1',
      href: '#item1'
    }, {
      title: 'Item2',
      subitems: [{
        title: 'Subitem 1',
        href: '#subitem 1'
      }, {
        title: 'Subitem 1',
        href: '#subitem 1'
      }]
    }, {
      title: 'Item3',
      href: '#item3'
    }];
  });
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
a,
a:visited,
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
ul.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #322f30;
  color: white;
}
.menuitem {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menuitem.active {
  background-color: #238db0;
}
.menuitem.active:hover {
  background-color: #238db0;
}
.menuitem:hover {
  background-color: royalblue;
}
.menuitem.subitems:after {
  content: '˅';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 15px;
  bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.menuitem.sub.active {
  background-color: #0c3441;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <sidebar></sidebar>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitarías dos atributos dentro de tu modelo, uno para cada menú, de forma tal de modificar el correcto. Algo así:

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="white-text" ng-click="openBar1 = !openBar1"><i class="material-icons">menu</i> <span ng-class="{'text-open-side-bar': !openBar1, 'text-close-side-bar': openBar1}">MENÚ</span></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><i class="material-icons">dashboard</i><span ng-class="{'text-open-side-bar': !openBar1, 'text-close-side-bar': openBar1}">Texto menu</span></a></li>
    <li class="sub-nav">
        <a ng-click="childrenOpen1 = !childrenOpen1"><i class="material-icons">dashboard</i><span ng-class="{'text-open-side-bar': !openBar1, 'text-close-side-bar': openBar1}">Texto menu</span><i class="nav-down material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</i></a>
        <ul class="children" ng-class="{'show-children':childrenOpen1,'hide-children':!childrenOpen1}">
          ..
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href=""><i class="material-icons">dashboard</i><span ng-class="{'text-open-side-bar': !openBar2, 'text-close-side-bar': openBar2}">Texto menu</span></a></li>
    <li class="sub-nav">
        <a ng-click="childrenOpen2 = !childrenOpen2"><i class="material-icons">dashboard</i><span ng-class="{'text-open-side-bar': !openBar2, 'text-close-side-bar': openBar2}">Texto menu</span><i class="nav-down material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</i></a>
        <ul class="children" ng-class="{'show-children':childrenOpen2,'hide-children':!childrenOpen2}">
          ...
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Así cada atributo está relacionado con el elemento correcot

Comment: mm la solución esta muy bien pero esta el inconveniente que si el menu sigue creciendo tengo que seguir agregando números para cada submenu hay alguna manera de hacer algo como:                                             // Mostramos y ocultamos submenus
 $('.submenu').click(function(){
  $(this).children('.children').slideToggle();
 });

Comment: @EdgarArmandHerreraPepe ahora comprendo mejor tu pregunta. La respuesta que dí está ligada específicamente al problema que expones y no al problema más general que tienes. Dejaré otra respuesta con una posible solución

Answer (score 0):

Angular (y los frameworks/librerías en general) está pensado para que durante el desarrollo necesites reescribir la menor cantidad de código, y te centres mejor en la planificación e implementación de la lógica del negocio. Es por esto que angular nos da la opción de utilizar [componentes](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component), que no son más que abstracciones de código que puedes reutilizar una y otra vez. Lo importante de estos, es que mantienen un scope interno, el cual no es compartido con el resto de los controllers, por lo que puedes tener 10 menús y cada uno tendría su propio estado interno (abierto/cerrado, por ejemplo).

Te dejo un ejemplo simple:

```js
var menuController = function(){
  var ctrl = this;
  
  ctrl.opened = false;

  ctrl.toggle = function(){
    ctrl.opened = !ctrl.opened;
  };
};


angular
.module('directiveApp', [])
.controller('controllerApp', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.menus = [
    {name: 'menu 1'},
    {name: 'menu 2'},
    {name: 'menu 3'},
    {name: 'menu 4'},    
  ];
}])
.component('menuComponent', {
  template: "<p class='menu' ng-click='$ctrl.toggle()'>{{$ctrl.name}}</p><ul ng-show='$ctrl.opened'><li>submenu</li></ul>",
  controller: menuController,
  bindings: {
    name: '<'
  }
});
```

```css
.menu {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid red;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="directiveApp">
  <div ng-controller="controllerApp">
    <p>Menus</p>
    
    <menu-component ng-repeat="menu in menus" name="menu.name" />

  </div>
</div>
```

**Esta es respuesta al problema general del usuario y no al código escrito por él**